# How to arrive at suggested approach number two in Zig Zag LeetCode question number 6

Tags: algorithm

I'm learning CS and I've been solving [LeetCode question number 6, ZigZag Conversion](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/), and I have came up with a solution that employs the same methodology as approach number one.

To educate myself, I tried understanding the approach number two, and I am having trouble seeing how can one devise those rules. They are described [here](https://leetcode.com/articles/zigzag-conversion/).

My problem is that although I can use their rules and I can devise those numbers from their formulas, I can't seem to have the mathematical prowess that allows me to see how could I have 'seen' it myself.

Question: If you have solved this question yourself, and you came up with the approach number two - what are the skills that you have employed in order to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't solved the problem myself but the skills I would use to think up a solution like the second approach would be analysis and consideration of numerical/counting patterns. If we follow the zigzag along, it's immediately apparent that each straight column has length `num_rows` (except for possibly the last). Thinking further, we realise that each diagonal also has the same number of characters except for the bottom and top it connects to. Hence we can count each south->northeast component as `num_rows + num_rows - 2` characters.

Using the logic above, we can write the formulas.

At row zero we have no offset:

```
k * (num_rows + num_rows - 2)
```

At the last row (`num_rows - 1`), we add the starting column that has offset our calculation:

```
k * (num_rows + num_rows - 2) + num_rows - 1
```

The middle is a bit trickier but basically the same. If we know the top of each vertical column, we add `i` to get at the `i`th row character:

```
k * (num_rows + num_rows - 2) + i
```

To get the character in the same row, on the diagonal "zag", that's after that column, we look at the start of the next column and subtract `i`:

```
(k + 1) * (num_rows + num_rows - 2) - i
```